# Error message: Conversion may lose significant digits

Tags: c

C Program to accept and display "5" characters using getchar() and putchar() functions:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  char ch[6];

  ch[0]=getchar();
  ch[1]=getchar();
  ch[2]=getchar();
  ch[3]=getchar();
  ch[4]=getchar();

  putchar(ch[0]);
  putchar(ch[1]);
  putchar(ch[2]);
  putchar(ch[3]);
  putchar(ch[4]);
}
```

When i am Compiling this code in "C" language then it is displaying this Error message: 
"Conversion may lose significant digits", what could be the reason?

Answer (score 5):

`getchar` returns an `int` and you're storing it in a `char`.

You can fix this by changing `char ch[6];` to `int ch[6];`.

Comment: I am using "Boreland C++" version 4.5

Answer (score 2):

`getchar()` returns an `int`, to allow for passing additional values which are not in the range of valid characters.  This allows for failures and error codes to be returned as values without overloading a particular character with multiple meanings.  In normal operation any valid character may be returned, in error operation an `int` that is too large to fit in a `char` is returned.

The warning message indicates that you are going to only look at the `char` portion of the returned value, and as such, you might oddly cast an error or special return value into a `char` that wasn't actually captured.

--- Edited at the request of gautham to demonstrate good error detection ---

The lack of error checking for input failure can be fixed in one of two ways.  The firs one is more common, and works on all systems where the size of an integer is greater than the size of a character.

```
  // an ok approach which works for most systems
  // provided that sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)
  int c = getchar();
  if (EOF != c) {
    ch[0] = (char)c;
  } else {
    // some error occurred during input capture
    // which resulted in getchar returning EOF
  }
```

The second solution to error checking for input failure doesn't rely on the size of an integer being larger than the size of a character.  It will work on all systems.

```
  // a better approach which works for all systems
  // even where sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)
  c = getchar();

  if (!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin)) {
    // even if c was EOF, we know it's a char value, not an error value
    ch[0] = c;
  } else {
    // c's value is EOF because of an error capturing the input, and
    // not because a char value equaling EOF was read.
  }
```

putting it all together to rewrite your program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char ch[6];

  ch[0]=getchar();
  ch[1]=getchar();
  ch[2]=getchar();
  ch[3]=getchar();
  ch[4]=getchar();

  putchar(ch[0]);
  putchar(ch[1]);
  putchar(ch[2]);
  putchar(ch[3]);
  putchar(ch[4]);

  return 0;
}
```

or if you have been introduced to procedures, the much better version of the above

```
#include<stdio.h>

char getInput() {
  int c = getchar();

  if (!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin)) {
    return (char)c;
  } else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char ch[6];

  ch[0]=getInput();
  ch[1]=getInput();
  ch[2]=getInput();
  ch[3]=getInput();
  ch[4]=getInput();

  putchar(ch[0]);
  putchar(ch[1]);
  putchar(ch[2]);
  putchar(ch[3]);
  putchar(ch[4]);

  return 0;
}
```

and if you have learned a bit about looping, it can be rewritten with a loop like so

```
#include<stdio.h>

char getInput() {
  int c = getchar();

  if (!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin)) {
    return (char)c;
  } else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char ch[6];
  int index;

  for (index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    ch[index] = getInput();
  }

  for (index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    putchar(ch[index]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

There are other checks you might want to add, like checking to see if your putchar failed due to an error during output; but, if you don't have an alternative means of presenting the error (like writing it to a file) then adding such checks only increase the complexity of the code without providing a means of communicating the error to the end user.

Error checking is one of the most important items in writing robust programs, but in most programming courses it is treated very lightly (if it is covered at all).  If you don't get much discussion about error checking, do yourself a favor and independently read over `<errno.h>`.  A decent description of how to handle errors in C can be found [in the GNU pages disussing error handling.](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Error-Reporting.html#Error-Reporting)  A basic "print to stderr" error handler might look like

```
 // this defines errno
 #include <errno.h>
 // this defines perror
 #include <stdio.h>
 // this defines strerror
 #include <string.h>

 extern volatile int errno;

 void printError(int value) {
   perror(strerror(value));
 }
```

Comment: It worked fine because the conditions which could raise an error didn't occur during that run of the program.

Comment: @gautham, the world is full of unexpected events.  Normally getchar responds with a char; but, sometimes things goes wrong.  When something goes wrong, getchar will reply with a non-char.  That way you know that it is something gone wrong, and not the input.  Errors include using getchar on something that cannot be read (invalid stdin), redirecting via shell a directory as stdin, the computer not having enough memory to buffer the input, the hardware failing, and many other conditions where it is not possible to read input.

Comment: @gautham, I don't know if there is a language problem; but, you seem to be ignoring what I have written.  Please try reading it again carefully.  Your code might work for a while, but it doesn't check possible error conditions.  When an error condition does exist, your code will then fail badly.  This is not a programming mistake like picking the wrong function or type, this is a programming mistake like not checking to see if an error occurred.  So it is sort of like backing up in a car.  It isn't that you are operating the machine wrong, it's that your not looking behind you.

Comment: @gautham, sorry if I wasn't clear.  My point was to not assume that getchar works every time.  That's why it returns a int, to make it easier to detect when it doesn't work.  Post has been updated to reflect your request for a re-code.

Comment: The only difference between is when the repeat-condition is checked.  The while statement looks like `while (condition) { block }` and the do-while looks like `do {block} while (condition)`.  In while, the repeat condition is checked before executing the block.  In do-while the repeat condition is checked after executing the block.  Since do-while checks the condition to repeat after executing the block, it will ALWAYS run the block at least once.  The simplest example of a while look looks like `while (true) { printf("hi"); }` and since the condition is never false, this loop will never end.